# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen error when running rake install:neo4j[community-latest, developement]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I am following this guide: https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/v10.0.1/Setup.html#generating-a-new-app

Tried setting the environment variable by running:

```bash
$ export NEO4J_DIST=http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-4.4.8-unix.tar.gz
```

but no luck.

Here is the trace log.

````
$ rake neo4j:install[community-4.4.8,development] --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::PerThreadRegistry is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1.
Use `Module#thread_mattr_accessor` instead.
 (called from <top (required)> at /home/aray/code/ruby/myapp/config/application.rb:17)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::PerThreadRegistry is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1.
Use `Module#thread_mattr_accessor` instead.
 (called from <top (required)> at /home/aray/code/ruby/myapp/config/application.rb:22)
** Invoke neo4j:install (first_time)
** Execute neo4j:install
Install Neo4j (development environment)...

rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-4.4.8-unix.tar.gz
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/download.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/download.rb:18:in `open'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/download.rb:18:in `fetch'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/server_manager.rb:303:in `download_neo4j'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/server_manager.rb:19:in `install'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/neo4j-rake_tasks-0.7.19/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/neo4j_server.rake:39:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:279:in `block in execute'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:279:in `each'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:279:in `execute'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/rake:25:in `load'
/home/aray/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => neo4j:install```
````

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with the library **neo4j-rake_tasks**. If you check the line referenced by the stack trace, you'll find this piece of code:

```ruby
def fetch(message)
  require 'open-uri'
  open(@url,
       content_length_proc: lambda do |total|
         create_progress_bar(message, total) if total && total > 0
       end,
       progress_proc: method(:update_progress_bar)).read
end
```

This is old Ruby (`< 2.4`). It used to be that after requiring `open-uri`, one could open a URL with `open`, as if it was a file. You can see it no longer works, as the error you get indicates it's trying to open an actual file (or some other local IO object). The way it *should* be now is with `URI.open` instead of just `open`.

The library seems to not be maintained anymore, so you'll have to take the matter into your own hands.